# Cómo puedo añadir una clase css a un único elemento dinámicamente mediante jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Es la primera vez que trabajo con jQuery. Estoy usando una librería de react para crear un árbol, pero el problema de usar la librería para agregar una clase es que necesito trabajar con la librería de jQuery.

Mi problema es que, como se puede ver en la foto, puede haber dos identificadores con el mismo número, por lo que la clase **tree-hover** del árbol se agrega dos veces en el árbol.

Como puede ver en mi código, lo primero que hago es eliminar todas las clases **tree-hover** del árbol que existan.

Luego busco el elemento con la identificación más cercana a la etiqueta para agregar la clase **tree-hover** a la etiqueta.

Pero como hay dos elementos con el mismo id, agrega la clase **tree-hover** dos veces.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
selectTreeHoverClass = id => {
    const numberId = parseInt(id);
    $(".tree-hover").removeClass("tree-hover");
    $("[hid='" + numberId + "']").closest("label").addClass(" tree-hover");
};
```

Pero creo que la forma más optima es buscar el elemento pasándole el id y su tipo, los cuales pueden ser: "hierarchy" o "dma".

El problema es que el siguiente código no me encuentra el label más cercano:

```
 $("[hid='" + `${numberId}-${type}`+ "']").closest("label").addClass(" tree-hover");
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el label más cercano pasándole el id y el tipo mediante jQuery?

Os pongo una captura del html que genera.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Javier, veo de entrada que tienes dos problemas: 1. Los identificadores siempre deben ser únicos en la página, de otro modo su uso no tiene sentido y generará errores. 2. No deberías mezclar React + jQuery. Dicho esto: busca la forma de hacer los identificadores únicos y la forma que tiene React para hacer lo que necesites, descarta el uso de jQuery en este caso.

Comment: Lo sé, pero la maldita librería para crear el árbol no me permite accedes a ella mientras se construye.Y si te das cuenta, en cierta manera los identificadores son "únicos" ya que uno es de la jerarquíe xxx-1-hierarchy y el otro es del árbol xxxx-1-dma

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado :)

Comment: Comparte como has solucionado, así ayudas a futuros visitantes del sitio que tengan un problema similar al tuyo.

Answer (score 0):

Al final para diferenciar posibles duplicidades de ids numéricos también añado el tipo como yo pensaba.

A la hora de crear los labels compruebo si son de tipo "dma" o "hierarhcy" y se lo añado al campo hid.

```
<span
  className="pr-notif"
  hid={data.type === "hierarchy" ? `${data.id}-hierarchy` : `${data.id}-dma`}
  onClick={(e) => this.clickElement(data, e)}
>
  {data.olabel}
</span>
```

Luego ya, a la hora de buscar pues busco por el campo numérico más el tipo.

```
selectTreeHoverClass = (id, type) => {
    const numberId = parseInt(id);
    const item = numberId + "-" + type;
    $(".tree-hover").removeClass("tree-hover");
    $("[hid='" + item + "']").closest("label").addClass(" tree-hover");
};
```

Se que no es la mejor no es usar la librería esa porque me obliga a importar la librería jQuery.